# Firebase authWithCustomLogin: undefined is not a function

Tags: firebase, angularfire

I am trying to set up authentication for admin users for an angular app. I have so far created the following code:

```
$http.post('/customAuth/adminBDauth.php', {email: email, password:password}).success(function(data){
        var refAuth = new Firebase('https://<firebase-ref>');

        refAuth.authWithCustomToken(data, function(error, authData) {
  if (error) {
console.log("Login Failed!", error);
 } else {
console.log("Login Succeeded!", authData);
 }
   });         
        });
```

However the following error is occurring - TypeError: undefined is not a function (referring to authWithCustomToken)

I know that the Firebase ref is fine because I have logged its value to check. I also know that the firebase token is being generated (though aware that doesn't appear to be the problem here in any event).

I am stumped as to why this doesn't work and can't think of any other tests to run. Anyone had a similar problem or know how I might proceed?

Thanks

Comment: What version of the Firebase client are you using? This sounds like you're on an earlier version before `authWithCustomToken` was introduced into the API.

Comment: I'm using bower, which is telling me I'm using 2.0.6

Comment: That's strange. Can you reproduce this in a Plnker?

Comment: There's not enough here to repro your issue. That method does exist, assuming you are using the correct version of the SDK (which you must not be). Bower is insufficient for determining if any other area of your code actually includes a different version (bower is not your HTMl).

Answer (score 1):

Makesure you include dependency "$firebaseAuth" as it says here

```
app.controller("SampleCtrl", ["$scope", "$firebaseAuth",
  function($scope, $firebaseAuth) {
    var ref = new Firebase("https://<your-firebase>.firebaseio.com/");
    var auth = $firebaseAuth(ref);
    auth.$authWithOAuthPopup("facebook").then(function(authData) {
      console.log("Logged in as:", authData.uid);
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.error("Authentication failed: ", error);
    });
  }
]);
```

As well as installing [angularfire](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/quickstart.html#section-inject-services)

Comment: But authWithCustomToken is part of the firebase library not angularfire.